# Why is validating two random numbers during submission in a form not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I have the following code-behind:

```
Random rndNum;
int inFirstOne, inSecondOne;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rndNum = new Random();

    int inFirst = rndNum.Next(1, 51);
    int inSecond = rndNum.Next(50, 101);

    lblFirst.Text = inFirst.ToString();
    inFirstOne = inFirst;

    lblSecond.Text = inSecond.ToString();
    inSecondOne = inSecond;
}
public void ValidateForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strNum = tbValidation.Text;
    int inCalc = inFirstOne + inSecondOne;
    if (inCalc.ToString() == strNum)
    {
        lblIsValid.Text = "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        lblIsValid.Text = "Please enter the correct result";
        lblIsValid.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
    }
}
```

ASP.net code:

```
...
<tr>
    <td><h2>What is <asp:Label ID="lblFirst" Text="" CssClass="numGen" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /> + <asp:Label ID="lblSecond" Text="" CssClass="numGen" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />?</h2></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbValidation" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="tbTech" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <asp:Label ID="lblIsValid" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="setRight">
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="ValidateForm" CssClass="btn" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

I am always seeing `Please enter the correct result` message.

How can I modify to ensure when the result is entered it works to validate the calculation from code-behind.

Comment: Have you looked at the values in the debugger?  Does one value have different precision or formatting (commas, etc.)? You might also have better success comparing the _numeric_ value rather than the _string_ representation.

Comment: Explain (to yourself) in words what you expect this to do. Then place some breakpoints, attach the debugger, and step through your code, comparing what you see to what you expect. My best guess: you really don't want to regenerate the numbers every Page_Load(), especially not when it's a postback.

Comment: Or better yet, explain it to a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: So the number is properly set in the `Page_Load()` event but inside the `ValidateForm` function, the two variable are 0.

Comment: `int inCalc = Convert.ToInt32(lblFirst.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(lblSecond.Text);` worked. the two variable are resetting to 0 for some reason :/

Comment: You can't keep field values between postbacks. A new instance of the page is created for each request.

Comment: @Guffa I ended up using the value of the label itself and it worked fine for me. I answer it so other people can also it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int inCalc = Convert.ToInt32(lblFirst.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(lblSecond.Text);` worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you're filling `tbValidation` but in any case unless you execute your `page_load` logic only if request it's not postback, variables `inFirstOne` and `inSecondOne`will be overwritten on button click.

It seems you need to have this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostback)
    {
        // do this only if it's the first request
        rndNum = new Random();

        int inFirst = rndNum.Next(1, 51);
        int inSecond = rndNum.Next(50, 101);

        lblFirst.Text = inFirst.ToString();
        inFirstOne = inFirst;

        lblSecond.Text = inSecond.ToString();
        inSecondOne = inSecond
    }
}
```

Comment: So the number is properly set in the `Page_Load()` event but inside the `ValidateForm` function, the two variable are 0.

Comment: `int inCalc = Convert.ToInt32(lblFirst.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(lblSecond.Text);` worked. the two variable are resetting to 0 for some reason :/